# Toast Notification: ArgumentOutOfRangeException on Image SetAttribute

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, toast

While working with ToastNotification in Windows RT, I got this error right on part of setting attribute of image element:

[image]

I tried using different path and image file name and none has worked so far.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm terribly sorry, it was a foolish mistake of mine.

Instead of

```
var toastImagesElements = toastXML.GetElementsByTagName("image");
```

i type

```
var toastImagesElements = toastXML.GetElementsByTagName("images");
```

That mistake makes `toastImagesElements` variable become empty. A little bit of focus would have saved me hours of suffering.

Thank you